# Linker errors from CMake script compiling project using Github repository code

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I've cloned this Github project:

https://github.com/machinezone/IXWebSocket

pasted the example code to my own empty project, main.cpp (pasted below) and written a basic CMakeLists.txt (pasted below).

The cloned Github project compiles/links fine and outputs a library:  `IXWebSocket/build/libixwebsocket.a`

The example code (now within my project) compiles but I'm getting problems with the linking. I used:

```
target_link_libraries(IXWebSocketTest <path/to/code>/IXWebSocket/build/libixwebsocket.a)
```

I'm currently getting this error as if the linking isn't correct:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/ld: DWARF error: invalid or unhandled FORM value: 0x23
IXWebSocket/build/libixwebsocket.a(IXWebSocketPerMessageDeflateCodec.cpp.o): in function `ix::WebSocketPerMessageDeflateCompressor::~WebSocketPerMessageDeflateCompressor()':
IXWebSocketPerMessageDeflateCodec.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld:
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(IXWebSocketTest)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
add_executable(IXWebSocketTest main.cpp)
include_directories("<path/to/code>/IXWebSocket/")

# I think this line might be wrong?
target_link_libraries(IXWebSocketTest <path/to/code>/IXWebSocket/build/libixwebsocket.a)
```

UPDATE

CMake file has changed to this:

```
add_executable(IXWebSocketTest main.cpp)
include_directories(<path>/IXWebSocket/")
find_package(ZLIB)
find_package(OpenSSL 1.1 REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(IXWebSocketTest OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto libixwebsocket.a ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

giving this command line:

> /usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -rdynamic
> CMakeFiles/IXWebSocketTest.dir/main.cpp.o -o IXWebSocketTest
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so -Wl,-Bstatic -lixwebsocket
> -Wl,-Bdynamic /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so

which is resulting in:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libixwebsocket.a(IXSocketOpenSSL.cpp.o): in function `ix::SocketOpenSSL::openSSLInitialize()':
IXSocketOpenSSL.cpp:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
/usr/bin/ld: IXSocketOpenSSL.cpp:(.text+0x221): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
/usr/bin/ld: IXSocketOpenSSL.cpp:(.text+0x230): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libixwebsocket.a(IXSocketOpenSSL.cpp.o): in function `ix::SocketOpenSSL::getSSLError[abi:cxx11](int)':
IXSocketOpenSSL.cpp:(.text+0x2fc): undefined reference to `SSL_get_error'
/usr/bin/ld: IXSocketOpenSSL.cpp:(.text+0x38e): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
/usr/bin/ld: IXSocketOpenSSL.cpp:(.text+0x3dc): undefined reference to `ERR_error_string'
/usr/bin/ld: IXSocketOpenSSL.cpp:(.text+0x49c): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
/usr/bin/ld: IXSocketOpenSSL.cpp:(.text+0x4e3): undefined reference to `ERR_error_string'
```

Comment: Looks like the project generates a config.cmake file: [https://github.com/machinezone/IXWebSocket/blob/master/ixwebsocket-config.cmake.in](https://github.com/machinezone/IXWebSocket/blob/master/ixwebsocket-config.cmake.in) but since you are not using `find_package(IXWebSocket REQUIRED)` you are not using it to add the additional zlib dependency to your link.

Comment: @drescherjm Is it possible to use their CMake file?  The problem is it adds subdirectories etc, which my project doesn't have (I literally just have main.cpp). Is it a case of going through and removing what should belong?

Comment: @drescherjm I guess what i'm asking is: what's the easiest way to write a CMake script which uses a n existing Github project? Is it a case of dissecting every line of their CMake and re-writing my own?

Comment: I normally don't change the CMakeLists.txt for the gitbub project. I just build it independently of my code in a separate folder.

Comment: @drescherjm What if you want to use that code in your own project?

Comment: If you are talking about the example projects for a library and I wanted to modify the example in that case I do edit the sample project so that it works in my project / solution. I still think you want to add `find_package(IXWebSocket REQUIRED)` to your CMakeLists.txt for this code then modify from there using the targets exported from the package. I can't help with specific details for this exact project because i would have to clone it and do some setup to even begin.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

build `libixwebsocket` as shared library `cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ...`

**Longer answer**

When you build a static library, its dependencies aren't actually built into the library. The compiler just makes marks that the dependencies will be provided later on the linkage stage. So, it's assumed you will provide them along with the library on the linkage stage. Possible solutions are

- build the library as shared
- connect `IXWebSocket` to your project as a dependency and build `libixwebsocket` as an intermediate step, CMake take care of dependencies then.

**UPD**

From documentation of IXWebSocket

```
$ clang++ --std=c++11 --stdlib=libc++ main.cpp -lixwebsocket -lz -framework Security -framework Foundation
```

So, it's assumed you should link against `zlib`. Your CMakeLists.txt should look like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(IXWebSocketTest)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
add_executable(IXWebSocketTest main.cpp)
include_directories("<path/to/code>/IXWebSocket/")

find_package(ZLIB)

# I think this line might be wrong?
target_link_libraries(IXWebSocketTest <path/to/code>/IXWebSocket/build/libixwebsocket.a ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

Also, you probably will have to enable c++11

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i'm trying to achieve the latter. I'm fairly new to CMake, so I want to research how to add a CMake dependency project?

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I think my current issue is it's not linking against OpenSSL even though I have: `target_link_libraries(IXWebSocketTest OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto libixwebsocket.a ZLIB::ZLIB)` . I get the error "undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'"

Comment: I'll update my Q with what I now see...

Comment: Okay, updated. I'm baffled why i'm getting SSL linker errors when both SSL libraries are being linked.

Comment: Fixed it. I had the linker library includes in the wrong order!!!